# Goodix fingerprint driver linux?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, fingerprint-reader

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
```

I am unable to find the driver for this fingerprint scanner.

Comment: There isn't one yet.

Answer (score 5):

There is something out there :
https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9300-Does-fingerprint-reader-work-on-linux/m-p/7628310/highlight/true#M63982

I did install it, and it works. Recognition is not very fast, but it do work.

```
sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-dell.list << EOF
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-dell public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-dell public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-oem public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-oem public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville public

deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville-melisa public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-somerville-melisa public
EOF'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9FDA6BED73CDC22
sudo apt update -qq

sudo apt install oem-somerville-melisa-meta libfprint-2-tod1-goodix oem-somerville-meta tlp-config -y
```

That was the repos for Ubuntu focal, but it works for newer version as well.

Comment: Note that this driver is only for Goodix 0x27C6 0x533C, 0x538C, 0x530C and 0x5840, not the 0x5395 that OP has.  See: https://launchpad.net/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the results on Linux-Hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:27c6-5395), there is very little support for that particular device at the moment. It seems to be detectable with Kernel versions 5.12 and newer however, looking at the hardware compatibility list, the machines that can detect it are limited to just detection.

Fingerprint sensors are notoriously difficult to support because companies like Shenzen Goodix rarely do anything for operating systems that are not Windows. Even with Windows the driver support is suboptimal. As a result, the teams that work on the fingerprint drivers for Linux are reverse-engineering the hardware only when they have it in their possession.

That said, with Kernel 5.12 having better support to at least *detect* the device, hopefully there will be an effort to make it work with Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions) in the near future.