# Lenovo ThinkBook 14 G2 : I can't use fingerprint sensor in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: lenovo, 22.04, fingerprint-reader

I have Lenovo Thinkbook 14 G2 and Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm unable to use the fingerprint scanner for login. Also I don't see frintprint option in user setting.

My device information is as follows:

`ID 27c6:55a4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device`

Comment: looks like your fingerprint sensor is not supported by `libfprint`, see this [list of supported devices](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341912/goodix-fingerprint-driver-linux

Comment: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:27c6-55a4&page=1#status

Answer (score 0):

I think that `fprint` will solve the problem you have.
Link to the [documentation](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/).

According to descriptions you'll need to perform following steps:

1. Install

   sudo apt install libpam-fprintd
2. First test it by running following command in the terminal

   fprint_demo
3. Save the fingerprint, which will make your login screen to require a finger swipe instead of a pass

   fprint-enroll

Info:
In some cases you'll need to activate fingerprint reader for elevated privileges for example with `sudo` by running following command `sudo pam-auth-update`

Comment: fprint_demo command did not worked, and i tried fprintd-enroll as instructed in the linked document. but fprintd-enroll gives an error as "Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available"

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Bashir no solution yet. it works fine on window 11 though